# json - Encryption SSL/TLS End to End

Tags: json, security, ssl, encryption

So a little back story about the security and project. Developing a private application for a customer. This application will need to be secure. One way we are securing it is by not allowing outside connections to this. Which means that only internal connections can be made. Or connections over VPN which we will pawn the security off of this to the VPN provider. However we must address and have in our minds the security concern of local users. We had many thoughts of this by simply pawning the security off on level 2 network devices and ldap security within the organization. However we now face the struggle of within the authorized user set (some very smart people) how do we keep security here.

So question is. If we have an SSL layering the application. Only allowing users to access the webserver via an SSL connection. Will it secure all traffic?

Scenario:

User A logs on to this website running on IP address 10.x.x.180(under the ssl).

User B is sitting with wireshark open and is sniffing in this network for any traffic to ip of 10.x.x.180.

User A makes a call to website to view a webpage. This webpage calls for a local json file on this server. Returns json to the application. Then this json is read and displayed to User A.

Q. Will User B be able to see this data in his sniffing packets? or will he simply see SSL encrypted data?

Comment: Please keep in mind that TLS will secure your tunnel (that is the traffic between the browser or app and the server will be encrypted). It will not help with the security of the application: someone who can log into it (whether this is a classical web site or an API) can try to hack it. Since you will be running in a restricted network with, as you called them, smart people, this is something which you should address as well (TLS is a simple configuration, securing your app is not).

Comment: @WoJ - I appreciate your concern. However the concern was more about another "hacker" not necessarily user. But i did not wish to write this. in case the "hacker" was able to grab a session from another user inside the complex by hijacking their computer or what have you. It limits that hacker to only that person's data and not other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q. Will User B be able to see this data in his sniffing packets? or
>   will he simply see SSL encrypted data?

He will only see the encrypted SSL traffic which provides an end-to-end encryption.

Comment: Thank you. Once I am able to accept this. I will. We are just concerned as some users have access to certain data and others have access to other data. We will be handling this security in our application. but I don't want user B to try to sniff data from another user essentially.

Comment: With SSL it is guaranteed that a man-in-the-middle will not be able to see the plain data exchanged over the wire. That's why SSL was created in the first place. Just make sure that all requests are made over an encrypted channel (HTTPS).